# dispatch is not accessible from useContext

Tags: reactjs, jsx, aws-amplify, react-context, use-context

i have simple store

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import Reducer from "./UserReducer";

const initialState = {
    user: {},
    error: null
};

const Store = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, initialState);
    return (
        <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    );
};

export const Context = createContext(initialState);
export default Store;
```

i have wrapped my app with it like

```
<Store>
    <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Navbar />
        <Wrapper>
            <Profile />
        </Wrapper>
    </ThemeProvider>{" "}
</Store>
```

There is additional setup as well where my authentication pages are located in separate wrapper so i wrapped that with store as well.

here is code for that wrapper (extra removed).

```
import Store from "../../../context/Store";
export default function Wrapper({ children }) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Store>
           //different dumb containers opening
                {children}
          //different dumb containers closing
        </Store>
    );
}
```

Now when i try to access context within child component like

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Context } from "../../../context/Store";
import { SET_USER } from "../../../context/UserTypes";

function SignUp(props) {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({ ...initialState });

    const [userData, dispatch] = useContext(Context);
    console.log(userData, dispatch, "check");
// rest of component
```

i get following error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

i tried to log result of useContext without destructuring it but all it had was global state but no dispatch function with it.

Reactjs version = 17.0.1

Update: dispatch is accessible outside withAuthenticator HOC but not within that so it might be amplify issue.

i have opened issue on amplify repo.

[Unable to access dispatch from useContext from components wrapped withAuthenticator](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/7467)

Answer (score 1):

There a few things I see that could be potential issues.

The major problem is the value of your `Context`.  When you create the context, its value is a state (`createContext(initialState)`).  But when you pass a `value` to the `Context.Provider` you are giving it an array which contains both a state and a dispatch function (`value={[state, dispatch]}`).  You need to be consistent about the value that is contained in the context.  Is it a state object or a tuple?

The error that you are describing seems like what would happen if the `Context` is accessed outside of a `Provider`.  It would fall back the initial context value which is just a state rather than a `[state, dispatch]` tuple.

You need to change the initial value to something that matches the value that you are expecting.

```
const Context = createContext([
  initialState, // state
  () => console.error("Cannot dispatch because Context was used outside of a provider") // dispatch
]);
```

But you also need to figure out why the `useContext` is getting the default value instead of one from a `Provider`.  I'm not sure if these next two issues will fix that or not.

It looks like the `Profile` component is inside of two different `Store` providers.  One which is outside of everything and one which is inside of the `Wrapper` component.  These will have two separate instances of state.  When there are two providers for the same context React uses the inner one.  So any actions that you dispatch from `Profile` won't update the outer version of `Store`.

You create the `Context` variable *after* you use it in your `Store` component.  You should switch the order.

Comment: last line about the order of usage somehow hinted me about my problem. I was using Provider as a dynamically added component. That was the problem. I used provider as a wrapper of the dynamically added(rendered) component and problem resolved.