# Unable to pass objects state and dispatch to provider when using createContext and useReducer with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings, react-context

I am trying to have a behaviour similar to the redux' using `contextApi` and hooks, but I'm having some trouble with typescript.

I want to provide both the state of my application and the dispatch to be able to access and modify the store from within a component. The issue is that when I use createContext, I still don't have neither the `state` nor the `dispatch` objects at hand, because I can only call `useReducer` inside a `React` component. Therefore I was only able to call `createContext` declaring that the type of the argument is `any` , in order to pass null at that point and pass another dispatch and state later on.

```
    import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
    import reducerAuth, { initialState } from './reducerAuth';
    const ContextAuth = createContext<any>(null);
    const StateProvider = (
      { children }:{children:JSX.Element},
    ) => {
      const { Provider } = ContextAuth;
      const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducerAuth, initialState);
      return (<Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</Provider>);
    };
    export { ContextAuth, StateProvider };
```

Is there a way which I can pass `state` and `dispatch` without having to declare type `any` and without having typescript conflicts?

I didn't want to use `redux` to achieve all of this, because I want to use native tools, but redux seemed easier, even though very similar.

I tyed to pass the type of the object `{state,dispatch}` to create context, the following way:

```
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducerAuth, initialState);
      type UseReducer = {
        state: typeof state,
        dispatch: typeof dispatch,
      }
      const ContextAuth = createContext<UseReducer | null>(null);
```

But in this case I am no longer able to export Context Auth, because it is then created inside the `StateProvider` function.

Comment: You probably have a type/interface somewhere to define the state object, right? Just use that when creating the context: `const ContextAuth = createContext<MyStateType>(undefined);`

Comment: I edited the question to explain the problem I had when trying this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you are trying to infer the type of an object after it's been created rather than understanding what type of object will be created.  In my opinion, this is a backwards design.

It is better to avoid using `typeof` when possible.  There are things that you can make clear with a `type` or `interface` that `typeof` cannot possibly infer on its own.  Can the `string` "myString" be any `string` value, or is it a string literal?  Can this `null` property only ever be `null`, or could it be `null` or some other type?  And what other type would that be?  Hopefully you get the point.

`dispatch` has a known type.  It is a function which takes an action and returns `void`.  You do not need to use `typeof dispatch` to get its type.

```
type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;
```

The generic variable `A` represents the acceptable `action` arguments.  What you use depends on how strictly-typed you want your app to be. You could set it to a union of your specific action types or to a general interface that all of your actions will fulfill.  Redux exports general types [`Action`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/1fc762610bd82b14f1bf87b45ba609ff4fdf1393/src/types/actions.ts#L18) and [`AnyAction`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/1fc762610bd82b14f1bf87b45ba609ff4fdf1393/src/types/actions.ts#L28) but React doesn't, so you have to define it yourself.

```
interface MyAction {
  type: string;
  payload: any;
}
```

```
type MyDispatch = Dispatch<MyAction>
```

Likewise, you should already know the expected type/interface for your `State`.  If not, define it!

Here is a complete code example.  The place to implement the types is on your `initialState` and `reducerAuth`.  If those are typed properly, then `StateProvider` does not need any extra typing as the `useReducer` hook can infer the types of `state` and `dispatch`.

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';

interface MyState {
    // some actual data here
}

// initialState must fulfill the `MyState` interface
const initialState: MyState = {};

// just an example, you can define this type however you want
interface MyAction {
    type: string;
    payload: any;
}

// reducer declaration depends on the types for `MyState` and `MyAction`
const reducerAuth = (state: MyState, action: MyAction): MyState => {
    // actual reducer here
    return state;
};

// these are the values in your context object
interface MyContext {
    state: MyState;
    dispatch: React.Dispatch<MyAction>
}

const ContextAuth = createContext<MyContext | null>(null);

const StateProvider = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
    const { Provider } = ContextAuth;
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducerAuth, initialState);
    return (
        <Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    );
};
```

Comment: This answer was great! But It also generated another small issue. Now, typescript can no longer recognize {state, dispatch} through destructuring, as you can see in: 
`const { state, dispatch } = useContext(ContextAuth);`
Typescript says it can't find `{ state, dispatch }` in type `< Context | null >`. State and dispatch do exist in Context, but obviously not in null.
const Context = useContext(ContextAuth);
```
     if (Context !== null) {
     const { state, dispatch } = Context;
      }
```
I could solve this with this snippet, but I found it a bit cumbersome. Any tips about this?

Comment: I found a better way, simply used:
`const { state, dispatch } = useContext(ContextAuth) as Context` Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I actually answered another question yesterday where I showed how to set a default value for the context which contains a state (from your initial state) and a dispatch (dummy function): https://stackoverflow.com/a/65866029/10431574